# can anybody suggest me some domain name ending words like "fy", "gram" etc

Tags: domains, idea

I want to buy a domain for my blog. I have my first word which is related to my business but I am looking for some good ending words like somethingfy, somethinggram, etc...can anyone list or provide some link to list of such ending words...I have looked at some domain name tools to get ideas but didnt achieve anything out of it...I hope I get some list here.

Answer (score 2):

Some search results for **words ending with *'fy'***:

- http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/fy/
- http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/fy/
- http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_fy.php
- http://www.yougorhymes.com/words-ending-with/fy
- [...](http://www.google.com/search?q=words+ending+with+%27fy%27)

and some results for **words ending with *'gram'***:

- http://www.morewords.com/ends-with/gram/
- http://www.scrabblefinder.com/ends-with/gram/
- http://www.wordbyletter.com/suffixes/words_finishing_with_gram.php
- http://www.yougorhymes.com/words-ending-with/gram
- [...](http://www.google.com/search?q=words+ending+with+%27gram%27)

[...](http://www.bing.com/search?q=words+ending+with+fy) you get the idea.

Cheers! ;)

Comment: thats not what I am looking for, I am looking for ending words like fy or gram, for example if my business is about shopping then my domain could be shopify or shopgram similar way I have that start word I just need ending word, like these two